# Load curve control via differential pair

Tags: amplifier, ltspice, signal-processing, differential, sawtooth-waveform

Last few weeks I have been designing a circuit, which is inputted with saw wave and outputs (amplification fairly linearly if possible) amplified voltage across two loads, where load voltage/current signals are symmetric but inverted - this is done via differential pair.

This is fairly simple, but what is not is gaining control over the setting of *meeting point* - the point at which two load curves intercept (have equal value of voltage/current at that time) while having range of output load voltage unaltered (that is 0 to \$V_{peak}\$). The current setup of adjusting meeting point is kind of unpractical, since multiple parameters need modification.

As **conclusion** I could say that I'm trying to achieve adjustment of one of circuit's parameters in order to modify load curve meeting point while load voltage swings from 0 to \$V_{peak}\$ (whereas \$ V_{peak} \$ value stays constant for all possible settings of meeting point).

[image]

Here are some of my side notes to this design (as extra):

[image]
Modifying *meeting point* means changing voltage level at which two load curves meet, as one increases and other decreases. In achieving such task I have been trying to somewhat adjust \$V_{bias}\$ and \$V_{src}\$ (in some cases also adjusting \$R_2\$ slightly in order to achieve symmetrical peak values).

As it can be seen from my notes, I tried *coupled* and *uncoupled* approach of input source. In both cases \$V_{bias}\$ **and** \$V_{src}\$ need modification in order to alter meeting point of load curves, but also \$V_{peak}\$ changes with each modification.

Here is what I refer to *meeting point* modification (from left to right; decreasing meeting point):

[image]

Should I either try a different approach (not with differential pair), add some kind of additional circuit to this one or is such circuit sufficient for stated requirements but should meeting point be adjusted somehow differently?

*P.S.: I'm almost certain that coupled design might not be best idea, since input capacitor should be very high, which makes \$ \tau=R_{input}*C_{coupling} \$ high and that is a problem since in takes a lot of time for output load curves to become symmetrical (due to \$ C_{coupling} \$ slowly charging and bias of \$ Q_1 \$ slowly approaching desired bias voltage, where both collector DC voltages of differential pair are the same).
Also, this circuit is meant to be operating at VLF (output saw wave period not less than 1 \$ s \$).

\$ EDIT: \$ As mentioned in the comment section, my real intention is to vary slope of modified saw signal while maintaining signal's frequency - analogy of such signal somewhat similar to PWM, where one controls *OFF* and *ON* time of square wave. Imagine this signal similar to PWM, instead of progressively shortening *ON* time, one could shorten part of period, where signal's amplitude is increasing but so would increase the signal's slope in order to maintain signal's frequency. The idea is visualized in a time graph above (observe only one curve of three different situations and you can see, how period of signal remains unchanged when *OFF* time is "implemented" but slope of the period, where signal's amplitude increases, also increases).

Here is how I imagined this signal to be generated, as *OFF* time would be increased:
[image]

Such circuit would then be a part of a system, where saw wave at the input is generated with microcontroller via DAC and modified signal of saw wave is driving the load. Also there is an option of controlling certain parameters of a signal conditioning circuit (the one that is shown above) like amplitude swing of input saw wave and its offset, plus tail current of differential pair with bias voltage of \$ Q_5 \$.

[image]

Comment: I think what you're trying to achieve will always be difficult with this type of circuit that has no **feedback**. You're directly dependent on the transfer function of the diff. pair which is never linear. I would forget about this type of circuit and use a circuit based on **opamps** instead. With opamps and feedback you can get almost ideal behavior.

Comment: As far as the simulation goes, if what you want is to actually build this, the very first step should be to test the validity of the models. And if you're using more than one device of a type, it's guaranteed they will not be identical, so you'll have to add those differences yourself (use [`ako`](http://ltwiki.org/?title=Undocumented_LTspice#AKO_Aliases_.28A_Kind_Of.29), and `mc()` or `gauss()`, for example). Not lastly, while you could make a discrete amplifier to be linear, unless it's a strict requirement, I'd also go for an opamp.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I get that - using op amps to improve linearity. However I cannot figure out how could I achieve this using op amp. The required task is that output produces variation of saw wave signal, where one could control *OFF* time while having period of output signal constant (which means if there is no *OFF* time, slope of signal is here the lowest, and on the other hand, if *OFF* time is the highest (for example 80% of period), slope of increasing part of period is the highest).

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Might sound stupid or difficult to understand, but what I'm trying to achieve here is like PWM, except that instead of increasing duty cycle (that is *ON* time) one could increase (vary) slope of saw wave, while maintaining constant period of a signal (what I'm trying to describe with words here is shown (in a way) at the last picture in my question, where I'm trying to explain myself what I mean with *"modifying meeting point of two load curves"*).

Comment: I suggest that you take a step back and draw a **block diagram** of a system that could do what you just described. For the "classic" way to make a PWM signal that would be a sawtooth generator, varying DC voltage (to control the DuCy) and a comparator. Most DCDC converters use this. I understand you want something different. Do realize that changing the slope of the sawtooth while maintaining the frequency has a direct impact on the sawtooth's amplitude, I mean: it will vary.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I should probably abandon the idea I'm referring to. I'm also most certain I lack some of basic understanding of a circuit (or subcircuit) that could perform such task. In some way, I might have to deal with some kind of modified saw wave oscillator, but have really no clue about that.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Here, added as much info in the edit as I could and described in detail, how I imagine this circuit (or any other) to work.

Comment: @Keno So, conceptually, what you want is the equivalent of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FEHs.png)? If so, that's a current source charging a capacitor, and another one discharging it, both proportional (or inverse) to the time. If you already have the sawtooth and you only need the amplifier, then an opamp would stil be a preferred way, unless you intend a differential output, in which case your driving and feedback will have to be [differential, too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddF8d.png) (a crude example, `V(x)` is the one from the previous picture).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Well, the part, where you managed to generate increased slope for increasing of signal is true, but falling should be immediate (or as fast as possible; at instant). Also, I intent to implement *OFF* period, where signal is 0, but then starts increasing with increased slope. Check the new edit, where I posted handwritten time diagram of how I want it to be (where *OFF* time is increased with each new period; period is constant - if *OFF* time increases, time of signal increasing should decrease proportionally).

Comment: @Keno Alright, but the simulation shows you have a sawtooth at the input , and your last diagram shows you have the uC for it? Why not just implement a variable resettable integrator, then DAC, then amplifier. Control from uC, only. But why differential? Is it because of the DAC? If the load is not differential, it's better to convert to single before power amp. If I'm not wrong, it seems a bit of an XY problem: you're focusing on the differential aspect, but the problem can be tackled without it. Also, control the amplitude, ok, but tail current?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Haven't thought about it but variable resettable integrator seems like a good idea. However frequency of integration would need to be varied (through digitally programmable resistor or maybe FET as voltage controlled resistor - both cases, resistance could be modified by MCU). On the other hand, required input PWM would also be generated by MCU. Haven't "swam" in these waters yet, so I don't really know, if mentioned system would work as intended to.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Oh, about tail current... Increasing it makes more current flow through differential pair. As input amplitude swing is increased (symmetrically "around" base bias in uncoupled design), tail current should be decreased to some extent, otherwise you get saturated output. I mean. such circuit would do for my need, I guess. But it really is impractical (I would say) to experimentally modify both input amplitude swing **and** tail current (through \$ Q_5 \$'s bias control) in order to get just the right *meeting point* of two curves and amplitude.

Comment: @Keno That's what I meant. The tail current is usually set at build time, then set in stone. Unless there is some educational value involved, there really isn't much sense. As for the integrator, all you need are two parameters: initial OFF delay, and integration constant (the period is presumed known, but if it isn't, it shouldn't be a problem). So just wait OFF seconds, then integrate/accumulate until the end of the period. The output amp should only care about amplification. At any rate, it was a suggestion; there ought to be about a million other ways to do it.